# Can text lines be modified while writting them to a file?

Tags: cmd

Can we add any string along with the TEXT we are writing or appending to a file.

For example

```
dir filepath/filename.txt >> file1.txt
```

I want to add a string (,ab) at the end of every line in file1.txt. In the same line and not in the next line.

somewhat like

source file

```
data1

data2

data3
```

target should be

```
data1,ab

data2,ab

data3,ab
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FOR` command for this purpose (see `HELP FOR` on the command prompt):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %i IN (filepath\filename.txt) DO ECHO %i,ab >> file1.txt
```

That will read each line from `filepath\filename.txt` and write it to `file1.txt`, with your `ab` appended.

Now, if you really wanted to execute the `dir filepath\filename.txt` command, and add the `ab` to its output, then you'd do the following

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %i IN (`dir filepath\filename.txt`) DO ECHO %i,ab >> file1.txt
```

or

```
FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('dir filepath\filename.txt') DO ECHO %i,ab >> file1.txt
```

Finally, note that if you want to put the above commands in a batch file, you need to escape the `%i` by writing `%%i`.

Additionally, to reduce noise if executed on the command line, you can use "@ECHO" instead of "ECHO", i.e. as @dbenham commented, prefix the DO-command with the "@" character.

Comment: `"delims=*"` might work fine for this case, the "common way" would be `"delims="` (no delimiters at all, so no need to find an unused character)

Comment: There is no need for USEBACKQ when capturing the output of a command. You could just as easily use `for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir filepath/filename.txt') do @echo %a,ab>>file1.txt`. Note that when run from the command line, the DO command should be prefixed with `@`.

Comment: @dbenham True, I guess I like the backquotes because of my UNIX "heritage" :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Christian K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27780562/1012053) using FOR /F is how you would do this using pure batch. There could be complications depending on the command output.

By default, FOR /F will skip lines beginning with `;` (the default EOL character). If you know of a character that cannot appear in the output, then you can simply set EOL to that character. But sometimes you have no control or knowledge of the potential output. There is an awkward syntax that disables both DELIMS and EOL, thus solving that problem.

Note that I prefix the DO command with `@` to prevent the command line from being echoed. I also enclose the entire construct within parentheses and redirect only once, as it is more efficient:

```
(for /f delims^=^ eol^= %A in ('someCommand') do @echo %A,ab)>file1.txt
```

But there is still a potential problem in that empty lines will be skipped. There is a solution using FINDSTR or FIND to prefix each line with the line number, and then remove the prefix within the loop. But that can slow things down.

It is much simpler to use my [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) that performs a regular expression search and replace on text. This is also much faster if you are dealing with a lot of output.

The following will append `,ab` to all lines of output, including empty lines:

```
someCommand | jrepl "$" ",ab" >>file1.txt
```

Your example implies that you do not want to append anything to empty lines. The following accomplishes that:

```
someCommand | jrepl ".$" "$&,ab" >>file1.txt
```